# How to detect changes in fingerprint during execution?

Tags: android, encryption, keystore, fingerprint

I want to detect when a fingerprint has been changed. That is why I am trying to check if there is any fingerprint attribute that changed during execution but no changes are taking place.

Is there any way to detect anything that let me know if the fingerprint has changed?

By now I've tried to check mac, cipher and provider CryptoObject's attributes in order to see if something changes with no luck.

> ```
>     FingerprintManagerCompat.CryptoObject cryptoObject = result.getCryptoObject();
>     try {
>         byte [] signatureArray = cryptoObject.getSignature().sign();
>         Tracer.d("Base: " + Base64.encodeToString(signatureArray, Base64.DEFAULT));
>     } catch (SignatureException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>     Mac    mac    = result.getCryptoObject().getMac();
>     Cipher cipher = result.getCryptoObject().getCipher().;
>     Provider provider = (cipher != null) ? cipher.getProvider() : null;
>     if (provider != null) {
>         String     info = provider.getInfo();
>         String     name = provider.getName();
>         Collection<Object> collection = provider.values();
>         if (collection != null) {
>             for (Object value : collection) {
>                 Tracer.d("Value: " + value.toString());
>             }
>         }
>         Tracer.d("Info: " + info);
>         Tracer.d("Name: " + name);
>     }
> ```